# error in android aplication - crash

Tags: java, android, crash

i have a crash with this code in my galaxy s but not in the simulator, where works fine

So, what is the possible cause of this error? thanks

```
package com.tct.soundTouch;

//imports ()

public class main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private MotionEvent event;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ImageButton zero = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        zero.setOnClickListener(this);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mp.pause();
            break;

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: add the crash log .. connect the device to computer and note down the log events.. only then we can help more

Comment: post the `logcat` so we can see the error.

Comment: logcat output during crash will be helpful to debug.

Comment: i can't connect the phone to the ubuntu. :(

Comment: You should be able to connect to the phone in Ubuntu. I suspect your problem is this: http://groups.google.com/group/android-discuss/browse_thread/thread/f85a795644e65b59

Comment: yes, it is exactly the same problem

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the system log, then surround your code with a try/catch block and spit out the exception in help of a dialog / text view.

My guess: The media format of your sound file isn't supported on the phone.

Comment: nop, i change the onTouch to onClick because of selectores (press, focus, etc in a xml file) and before of this change, the program works fine. It is a simple mp3